# Breezee and linqtosql

Tags: breeze

I'm new on Breezee, I'm looking the examples and Breezee has good support for EntityFramework.

```
readonly EFContextProvider<TodosContext> _contextProvider =
new EFContextProvider<TodosContext>();

// ~/breeze/todos/Metadata
[HttpGet]
public string Metadata() {
    return _contextProvider.Metadata();
}
```

But actually my data model is LinqToSql. Can I use Breezee with LinqToSql? How do I configure the metadata?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either

1) construct the metadata yourself on the server in json format and return that.  See [Metadata format](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breeze-metadata-format).

or

2) create the metadata on the client using the [MetadataStore api](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/MetadataStore.html) and then configure your dataservice so that it does not expect server side metadata. The Edmunds example in the Breeze zip shows an example of doing something like this.

```
    var dataService = new DataService({
        serviceName: "MyServiceName",
        hasServerMetadata: false
    });


    ver myEntityManager = new EntityManager({
        dataService: dataService,
    });
```